# How can fix table header on horizontal and virtical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using plugin to fixed table header horizontal and virtical scroll but it is working only horizonal scroll only. i want to freeze table head on both scroll any solution please help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fixTable").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "left" : 1}); 
});

use plugin 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html
```

Comment: please put a demo for better help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=arGIEP7IUs

Comment: you can cheak here

Comment: the demo code works. you're just not displaying enough rows for the fixed header to initiate. you'll also need to add jquery and the plugin script to your fiddle for the javascript to initiate.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/examples/fixHeadAndLeft.html

Comment: please click above link to check i need to fix table header on horizontal nad virtical scroll